# React Select Use State to set two different values

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-select, use-state

```
    import React from 'react'
    import {useState} from 'react'
    
    const SlctForm = () => {
     const [empHrs, setEmpMonHrs] = useState({
         day: null,
         start: null,
         end: null
     })
    
     const onHrChange = (event) => {
         setEmpHrs({
             day: event.target.name,
             start: event.target.value,
             end: event.target.value
         })
    
     }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                <select name='monday' onChange={onHrChange}>
                    <option value={7}>7</option>
                    <option value={9}>9</option>
                </select>
                <select name='monday' onChange={onHrChange}>
                    <option value={7}>7</option>
                    <option value={9}>9</option>
                </select>
                <select name='tuesday' onChange={onHrChange}>
                    <option value={7}>7</option>
                    <option value={9}>9</option>
                </select>
                <select name='tuesday' onChange={onHrChange}>
                    <option value={7}>7</option>
                    <option value={9}>9</option>
                </select>
                </form>
    
            </div>
        )
    }
  
 export default SlctForm
```

I am trying to create an array with objects, those objects should contain the weekday, start, and end time of each day. I think it would be best to use select to accomplish this. I can't seem to find anything that shows me how to set two different values for the same object. Can someone give me some direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wish to select a start and end time for each day, and store it in the state.

here is a possible solution. Let me know if it is what you want, and then I will elaborate

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-currying-zw250?file=/src/SelectForm.js)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const SlctForm = () => {
  const [empHrs, setEmpHrs] = useState([
    {
      day: "monday",
      start: null,
      end: null
    },
    {
      day: "tuesday",
      start: null,
      end: null
    }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(empHrs);
  }, [empHrs]);

  const onHrChange = (value, day, timeOfDay) => {
    setEmpHrs((prevState) => {
      let newState = [...prevState];
      const dayIndex = newState.findIndex((emp) => emp.day === day);

      newState[dayIndex] = {
        ...newState[dayIndex],
        [timeOfDay]: value
      };

      return newState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <select
          name="mondayStart"
          onChange={(e) => onHrChange(e.target.value, "monday", "start")}
        >
          <option value={7}>7</option>
          <option value={9}>9</option>
        </select>
        <select
          name="mondayEnd"
          onChange={(e) => onHrChange(e.target.value, "monday", "end")}
        >
          <option value={7}>7</option>
          <option value={9}>9</option>
        </select>
        <select
          name="tuesdayStart"
          onChange={(e) => onHrChange(e.target.value, "tuesday", "start")}
        >
          <option value={7}>7</option>
          <option value={9}>9</option>
        </select>
        <select
          name="tuesdayEnd"
          onChange={(e) => onHrChange(e.target.value, "tuesday", "end")}
        >
          <option value={7}>7</option>
          <option value={9}>9</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SlctForm;
```

Comment: This seems perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, glad to hear. Please accept the answer if it helped.